Overhead rack install on drywall with resilient channels
I purchased an overhead rack, specifically the Newage VersaRac Pro, to install on to the ceiling of my garage. Upon completing marking everything out, I quickly learned that the “studs” I marked out are actually resilient channels. This would mean that the drywall is indirectly mounted to the ceiling joists, with an air gap of however tall the resilient channels are (I’m guessing 0.5 inches).
My question is, because of this gap, will I have problems securing the rack to the joists? Will it warp or crack the drywall? Or even are far as to say to not even recommended to install the rack at all?

You have two primary options.
Mount as planned, but only tighten the screws lightly snug. If the screws are robust enough they won't flex under lateral loading so much as to be a problem. If they're questionably light, use heavier ones. 5/16" or 3/8" lag screws might be appropriate, depending on quantity and rack weight rating. If the contact points of your rack are very small, consider backing them with plywood or lumber to distribute force a bit and prevent gouging of the drywall.
ELEVATION (SIDE) VIEW
_________________________________________________ <-- framing
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- channel
_________________________________________________ <-- drywall
  |__________|              |__________| <-- backer plates
      ====                      ==== <-- rack feet
       ||                        || 

Or, install bushings to framing. You'd do this by drilling say ¾" holes through the steel channel, then installing something like a nylon bushing to flush with drywall or just proud of it (maybe 1¼" total) through which you'd insert your screws. Now you can snug down your mounting screws without concerns about crushing the drywall.
ELEVATION (SIDE) VIEW
___________________________________________________ <-- framing
~~~~~~~|  ''  |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|  ''  |~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- channel
_______|  ''  |_________________|  ''  |___________ <-- drywall
        --''--                   --''--  <-- bushings
         ====                     ==== <-- rack feet
          ||                       ||

In either case, be sure you have adequate screw penetration. Don't dismiss that lost half inch as insubstantial. I'd want at least 2" into framing.
